# Changing the colour of regions on an SVG circle tiled world map when hovered

Tags: javascript, css, svg, frontend

I am attempting to make a world map made from an svg comprising many circles. I based this from a codepen I found here: https://codepen.io/mvaneijgen/pen/NRzENO

E.g.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 845.2 458">
    <circle class="st0" cx="826.1" cy="110.3" r="1.9"/>
    <circle class="st0" cx="819.3" cy="110.3" r="1.9"/>
    <circle class="st0" cx="819.3" cy="117.1" r="1.9"/>
    <circle class="st0" cx="812.6" cy="90" r="1.9"/>
```

The map is great. I have been dividing it up into coloured continent regions using classes. These change colour when hovered over. All good so far. Most of my functionality is there.

The issue is that you have to be hovering directly on a circle to make the colour change happen. I am using a javascript mouseover event to change the colour.

Is there any way of increasing the area of effect around the circle elements? Maybe putting an invisible square either behind or in front? I am still getting to grips with front-end stuff and any pointers here would be great.

Answer (score 0):

That’s the right idea: transparent `rect`s behind each circle. (Or transparent continent-shaped paths based on geo data, depending on what you’re going for.)

The trick is to use the SVG CSS property [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). Setting it to `fill` or `all` should do the trick.

Comment: Won't that double the file size of my svg though? Can i do something using ::before or ::after?

Comment: Those are HTML DOM features, so don’t apply to SVG. There is a `pointer-events: bounding-box`, but I don’t think it’s well supported.